# Parse.com preventing whitespaces in custom tracking events?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, ios8, whitespace

2 months ago I added custom tracking events with whitespaces in my app, such as:

```
[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"Share Button Click" dimensions:dimensions];
```

However, it seems like Parse is no longer allowing whitespaces, which in turn has caused my code to  stop registering analytics. Does anyone know a fix around this?

Here's the error:

```
Error: invalid event name: cannot contain whitespace (Code: 160, Version: 1.4.2)
2014-11-01 runEventually command failed. Error:Error Domain=Parse Code=160 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 160.)" {code=160, error=invalid event name: cannot contain whitespace}
```

I'm curious as to why Parse has done this change and if there's anything we can do so that I'm not forced to create a new event.

Comment: Is this a new event you are trying to track or is this an old one that already has some tracking data available? As far as I know, old events with spaces should continue to work, only new ones are not allowed to have spaces anymore. If it is an old one, you might want to file a bug here https://www.parse.com/help

Comment: why would Parse remove partially remove a functionality like this? Seems very odd, if its already working don't change it, at least for old apps. Change at the app level, not the event level.

Comment: So, the fix is to simply use underscores, hyphens, etc. ?

Comment: Can anyone confirm if existing events are grandfathered ?